# Definition of canonical isomorphism between two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

I'm reading "Linear Algebra via Exterior Products" by Winitzki. The part leading up to the canonical isomorphism definition firstly proves the result that an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose the isomorphism is defined as $\hat{M}v = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, where the coordinates $x_i$ are given in the standard basis $\{e_i\}$.

Then it says:

> Note that the isomorphism $\hat{M}$ will depend on the choice of the
>   basis: a different basis $\{e′_i\}$ yields a different map
>   $\hat{M_1}$. For this reason, the isomorphism $\hat{M}$ is not
>   canonical.
>
> ...
>
> A linear map between two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is canonically
>   defined or canonical if it is defined independently of a choice of
>   bases in $V$ and $W$.

I can't understand why changing the basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ would yield a different linear map. Shouldn't the map remain the same? Only the **representation** of the output vectors would change because of the basis change.

And by that logic, for **any** linear map, changing the basis would change the coordinates, and hence the representation, of the output vectors. So what exactly is meant by a linear map "defined independently of the choice of bases"?

Comment: Two maps are different if their image on *at least* one element of hte domain is different...and this precisely happens in this case, of course, as linear maps are completely and uniquely determined by their values on **any** basis of the domain.

Comment: The map $\hat{M}$ _is_ the representation map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try and address what I see as the root of your question. Suppose I have two vector space $V$ and $W$ and a linear map $T : V \to W$ between them. Clearly, the action of $T$ on a vector $v \in V$ is independent of any bases $\beta,\gamma$ I may have chosen for $V$ and $W$. $T(v)$ is $T(v)$ no matter what bases I choose for $V$ and $W$.

Our situation here is much different. We haven't been *given* a linear transformation $T : V \to \Bbb R^n$ but are asked to *build* a linear transformation $\hat{M} : V \to \Bbb R^n$ which is an isomorphism. Here we first *choose* a basis $\beta = \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ for $V$ and then define

$$
\hat{M}(v) = \hat{M}(x_1v_1 + x_2v_2 + \cdots + x_nv_n) = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n).
$$

Because every vector in $V$ can be expanded uniquely as a linear combination of $\beta$, $\hat{M}$ is unique and well-defined. Such a map is sometimes called a representation map $\hat{M}$ as it "represents" elements of the abstract vector space $V$ in the concrete vector space $\Bbb R^n$.

However, if we pick a different basis $\beta'$ and compute a new representation map $\hat{M}'$, we have no guarantees that $\hat{M} = \hat{M}'$. In fact, if $\beta \ne \beta'$ then $\hat{M} \ne \hat{M}'$. Alejandro's answer gives a great example of how picking $\beta \ne \beta'$ does indeed give $\hat{M} \ne \hat{M'}$.

There is no contradiction here. We have simply built two different linear transformations $\hat{M}$ and $\hat{M}'$ using different bases. While $\hat{M}$ and $\hat{M}'$ are both *ways* of representing vectors in $V$ as vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ they are different transformations.

You might ask if its possible to build a map from $V$ to $\Bbb R^n$ *without* picking a basis first for $V$. This turns out to be impossible in general. Thus we may say there is no **canonical** isomorphism from $V$ to $\Bbb R^n$: any isomorphism from $V$ to $\Bbb R^n$ will depend on which basis you use to make the representation map.

For example, if I say to you that $V$ has dimension three, there is no way for me you can construct for me a linear map $T : V \to \Bbb R^3$ without picking a basis (or something equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the vector space of linear and constant polynomials with real coefficients:
$$V=\{a+bx: a,b \in \mathbb R\}.$$

Let's also consider the bases $B_1=\{1,x\}$ and $B_2=\{x,x+1\}$. If you express in each basis the polynomial $f(x)=2-3x$ you get
$$f(x)=2\cdot 1+(-3)\cdot x$$
and
$$f(x)=(-5)\cdot x+2\cdot (x+1).$$

Then, if we consider the first basis the isomorphism $\hat M$ is such that
$$\hat M(2-3x)=(2,-3)$$
but if we take the second basis we get
$$\hat M(2-3x)=(-5,2).$$

So that when you say "let $B$ be a basis...", the choice of that basis determines which homeomorphism you're defining.